# what "--from=builder" do in Dockerfile

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I am trying to understand the [dockerfile](https://github.com/monzo/egress-operator/blob/master/Dockerfile#L24) for implementing egress-operator. Can someone let me know what does line :

`COPY --from=builder /workspace/manager .` AND `ENTRYPOINT ["/manager"]` mean here and what are they trying to do at `ENTRYPOINT ["/manager"]` ?

Are they running manager script then it should be something like `ENTRYPOINT ["./manager"]` or they are trying simply `cd` to `/manager` folder ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`builder` is the name of a previous stage in the multi-stage Dockerfile. It is probably building the application `manager`. Once the `builder` is complete, this current stage copies the `manager` file into the current image /workspace directory. The entrypoint simply gives the program that will run when the container starts.

You can find more detailed explanations here:

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/

Comment: So you mean in Entrypoint[/manager] is a file that is being tried to run at entrypoint stage ? so it should be ./manager right ?

Comment: I don't understand the question. ENTRYPOINT is an array in which you can specify the program to run and its default arguments.

Comment: my que was that what is /manager meaning ? I understand that entrypoint simply execute whats inside it. But my que was that what exactly /manager will do ? will it run a file named "manager" ? or /manager is something related to golang and kubebuilder ?

Comment: ./manager will run the ./manager program. Based on your question, that manager program is built at the earlier stage of your Dockerfile.

Comment: so you think that instead of /manager , it should be ./manager in ENTRYPOINT ? (dot missing before / here: https://github.com/monzo/egress-operator/blob/master/Dockerfile#L27 )

Comment: You need the dot. Without the dot, exec relies on PATH search, and usually in dockerfiles path is not set.

Answer (score 5):

Normally a `COPY` command would copy a file from the build context into the image. But with `--from` it instead copies from the filesystem of a previous build stage. Somewhere above that you'll see `FROM whatever AS builder` and some build instructions, so it's copying from that.